# How to calculate/represent rate of change of a pixel in ImageJ

Tags: image-processing, statistics

The following is in reference to dynamic 16-bit images in ImageJ64.
I am aiming to be able to "plot" a rate of change for each pixel in the image for the whole sequence of images (60 per set) and use the different gradient values of this plot as representation of the change in that pixel over time thus displaying dynamic data as a still image.  Any ideas on where to start and any tools that may be of use?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible "rates of change", everything depends on particular application. Some of possible solutions include (assuming that `pix` is a set of a particular pixel's values across your images):

- values amplitude `max(pix)-min(pix)`
- values variance (or standard deviation) `var(pix)` (or `std(pix)`)

more complex functions can be used, if you are interested in actual "visual effect change" rather then simple pixel value by for example computing variance of directional partial derivatives etc. As stated before - everything depends on your application, what kind of change are you interested in.